# Emacs copy with regex

Tags: emacs

I have a text file.  Can Emacs select text based on regex and put it in kill-ring, so I can copy it somewhere else?  Something like regex-kill-ring-save?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inspired by the already given comments (the Charles answer doesn't work as I would want it), I added a new function to the isearch/isearch-regexp mode map which puts only the matching string into the kill ring (whereas Charles proposal kills from current point to end of matching string):

```
(defun hack-isearch-kill ()
   "Push current matching string into kill ring."
   (interactive)
   (kill-new (buffer-substring (point) isearch-other-end))
   (isearch-done))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-w") 'hack-isearch-kill)
```

The nice thing about the isearch/isearch-regexp approach (which you can enable with `C-s` and `C-M-s` respectively) is that you can see your search string growing and you can copy it with `M-w` as soon as you are satisfied (and go back to where you have been before with `C-u C-Space`).

This works for me with Emacs 23.1. Don't know if it will work in all situations. Anyway I hope you find it useful :)

**UPDATE:** going through the emacswiki I stumbled over [KillISearchMatch](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillISearchMatch) which suggests more or less the same (plus some more tips ...).

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I wanted, but couldn't make since I suck at LISP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is such a function already, but what you can do it with a keyboard macro:

1. Start recording a kbd macro: `C-x (`
2. Search for your regexp with `search-forward-regexp`
3. Move to the beginning of your match (the text you want to kill) with the various emacs navigation commands, e.g. `search` or `backward-word` etc.
4. Mark: `C-spc`
5. Move to the end of your match
6. Kill the text: `C-w`

You can then name the keyboard macro with `M-x name-last-kbd-macro` so that you can execute the macro with a name rather than with `C-x e`.

If you want to save the macro for future sessions, you can open your `.emacs` and insert the macro into the buffer with `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. After than you can bind a key to the macro just like you bind keys to normal emacs functions, e.g. `(global-set-key "\C-c m" 'funky-macro-macro)`.

[More about emacs keyboard macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros)

Answer (score 1):

[**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) does this already. It optionally sets the region around the search target. You can use `C-SPC C-SPC` or `M-= C-SPC` at any time during Isearch to toggle this.

> `isearchp-deactivate-region-flag` is a variable defined in `isearch+.el`.
>
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-nil means isearching deactivates the region.
>
> See also option `isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag`.
>   You can toggle this option using `M-= C-SPC` during Isearch.
>
> You can customize this variable.